# How can I prevent blank HTML form submissions to go through?

Tags: html, forms, form-submit

I am using **`Formspree`** (which is awesome) except: I have set all my fields to required, when I try manually I can't submit a form without filling everything properly, and however I still get a bunch of blank forms coming through. Has anybody experienced / fixed this before?

Thanks!

```html
<form action="https://formspree.io/XXXXXXXX" method="post">
<input name="_gotcha" style="display: none" type="text">

<input class="form-control input-lg" name="firstname" placeholder="First Name" required type="text">

<input class="form-control input-lg" name="lastname" placeholder="Last name" required type="text">

<input class="form-control input-lg" name="phone" placeholder="Phone number" required type="text">

<select required name="country" class="form-control input-lg" style="border-radius:none; -webkit-appearance: none; padding-top:0px;">
    <option value="" disabled selected>Please select your country </option>
    <option value="Afganistan">Afghanistan</option>
    <option value="Albania">Albania</option>
    <option value="other">Not in the List</option>
    <!-- etc -->
</select>

<input type="hidden" name="referrer" id="referrer_field" />
<input type="hidden" name="url" id="url_field" />

<button id="demo" type="submit">GO</button>
```

Comment: Please share your code. Can't help without any code to work on

Comment: Sry. Just added the code snippet above

Comment: which server side framework you are using. Can you add some server side code where you are getting null values for fields

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have access to the server side. It's a static bootstrap landing page that we use for quick iterations.

Comment: `required` can easily be bypassed, generally adding conditions to your PHP would resolve this such as `if (!empty($_POST['name_of_field']))`

Comment: The point of using formspree is to not have to use php / set up a mail server etc. So I guess that won't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

And this is another Solution for your code, as this will work even if somebody put "`spaces` or leave it with blank" in the field of Name or Phone.

Check the Fiddle..

```js
//  Bind the event handler to the "submit" JavaScript event
$('form').submit(function () {

    // Get the Login Name value and trim it
    var fname = $.trim($('#fname').val());
    var lname = $.trim($('#lname').val());
    var phon =$.trim($('#phon').val());

    // Check if empty of not
    if (fname === '') {
        alert('First name is empty.');
        return false;
    }
    else if (lname === '') {
        alert('Last Name is empty.');
        return false;
    }
    else if (phon === '') {
        alert('Phone is empty.');
        return false;
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="https://formspree.io/XXXXXXXX" method="post">
<input name="_gotcha" style="display: none" type="text">

<input class="form-control input-lg" name="firstname" placeholder="First Name" id="fname" required type="text">

<input class="form-control input-lg" name="lastname" placeholder="Last name" id="lname" required type="text">

<input class="form-control input-lg" name="phone" placeholder="Phone number" id="phon" required type="text">

<select name="country" class="form-control input-lg" style="border-radius:none; -webkit-appearance: none; padding-top:0px;">
    <option value="" disabled selected>Please select your country </option>
    <option value="Afganistan">Afghanistan</option>
    <option value="Albania">Albania</option>
    <option value="other">Not in the List</option>
    <!-- etc -->
</select>

<input type="hidden" name="referrer" id="referrer_field" />
<input type="hidden" name="url" id="url_field" />

<button id="demo" type="submit">GO</button>
```

If somebody type space to the input box then this Jquery code will work and ask him to fill proper text in fields.

Comment: You can check this, if you don't fill any word then `required` attribute will ask to Fill. But what if somebody put `space` in those fill, then My Jquery code will work.

Answer (score 2):

Try W3Schools example of
http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_required.asp

```
<input class="form-control input-lg" name="firstname" placeholder="First Name" required >
```

with no equals or anything

I thought the required tag was

required="True/false"

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution would be something like this. 
You can do this by using JQuery

```js
//  Bind the event handler to the "submit" JavaScript event
$('form').submit(function () {

    // Get the Login Name value and trim it
    var name = $.trim($('#log').val());

    // Check if empty of not
    if (name === '') {
        alert('Text-field is empty. You cannot leave is blank!');
        return false;
    }
});
```

```css
.text-label {
    color: #cdcdcd;
    font-weight: bold;
}
#pwd{
  margin:10px 18px;
  }

#logBtn{
  margin:10px 90px;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="login.php" method="post">
    <label>Login Name:</label>
    <input type="text" name="email" id="log" />
    <br/>
    <label>Password:</label>
    <input type="password" name="password" id="pwd" />
    <br/>
    <input type="submit" id="logBtn" name="submit" value="Login" />
</form>
```

Comment: Thx, gonna try it now!